# IIS returns 404 on WCF Actions

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have started making use of WCF Actions as per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2012/04/10/actions-in-wcf-data-services-part-1-service-author-code.aspx.

Everything works fine on IIS Express, but once deployed to IIS, I receive 404 errors from any service action. All other WCF interactions are working fine, with the exception of the Actions. It's as though IIS can't understand the route, or WCF is mistaking the service action for a relation. The service metadata does report the service action end point correctly however.

We are using WCF 5.6.3 and EF6.

Anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

2 things you may check:

1. There is a sample for that action provider could be found here, please check whether it works.

   http://efactionprovider.codeplex.com/
2. For using EF6 with WCF Data Service, you need some special configuration, please check the following posts:

   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx#diff

   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/08/18/wcf-data-services-entity-framework-provider-is-updated-with-wcf-data-service-5-6-2.aspx

Comment: Implemented all of those. It works 100% fine in my IIS Express environment. But once deployed to Windows 2008 Sever IIS, the service responds with 404 when executing any one of the Action's.

Comment: I have just found that this issue ONLY occurs on this one server. All other servers I have implemented it works just fine.